# Add template suggestions for location.tpl.php to use a different layout for addresses on specific content types?

Tags: 7, theming

I have been trying to figure out a method to override the locations.tpl.php template on a per content type basis, but I can't find any good examples on doing this with module template files rather than core template files. Is there code that could be inserted into template.php so that location--blog.tpl.php could be used in the same way that node--blog.tpl.php can be used? Interested in the location module specifically, but would appreciate pointers for general methods of theming contrib modules.

Answer (score 1):

@

**Drupal 7 Template Suggestions**
http://drupal.org/node/1089656

lists template suggestions in core.  It references,

***Custom Template Suggestions***

> Custom suggestions beyond the ones
>   listed below can be created. See the
>   page Working with template
>   suggestions.
>   http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions

which provides examples for mod'ing template.php so that "All layers from core, modules, theme engines and themes can provide the suggestions."

which may provide a start for you.

Comment: These pages are both for making page and node templates, I am looking more for some steps to override module templates in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function.

Paste it in your theme file `template.php`

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_preprocess_location(&$variables) {
    $query = db_select('location_instance', 'n');
    $nid_field = $query->addField('n', 'nid');
    $query->condition('lid', $variables['location']['lid']);
    $result = $query->execute();
    foreach($result as $n){
        $node = node_load($n->nid);
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'location__node__' . $node->type;      
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'location__node_' . $n->nid;       
    }
}
```

Your theme can now detect different templates for the locations original template using this pattern: **location--node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php**

For instance, these would be valid template suggestions:

```
location--node--1.tpl.php
location--node--blog.tpl.php
```

Comment: do this code could work for a D6 website ?